# Google AppEngine DataStore constistency

Tags: google-app-engine, consistency

My current understanding of Google AppEngine's High Replication DataStore is the following:

- ***Gets*** and *puts* of individual entities are always strongly consistent, i.e. once a *put* of this entry completes, no later *get* will ever return a version earlier than the completed *put*. Or, more precisely, as soon as any one *get* returns the new version, no later *get* will ever return the old version again.
- ***Gets*** and *puts* of multiple entities are strongly consistent, if they belong to the same ancestor group and are performed in a transaction, i.e. if I have two entities that are both being modified in a transaction by a *put* and "simultaneously" read in a different transaction with a *get*, the *get* will either return the old version of both entries or the new version of both entries, depending on whether the *put*-transaction has completed at the time of the *get* or not, but it will never return the old value of one entity and the new value of the other.
- **Queries with an ancestor filter can be chosen to be strongly or eventually consistent**, where a strongly consistent query takes longer to complete, but will always return the "same" version (old or new) of all entities updated in the same transaction in this ancestor group and never some old and some new versions.
- **Queries that span ancestors are always eventually consistent**, i.e. might return an old version of one result entity and a new version of another.

Did I get this right? Is this actually documented anywhere? (I only found some documentation about the query consistency [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Queries_and_indexes) (between the first and second "Note") and [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency), but it doesn't talk about *gets* and *puts*...)

Comment: For the record I would take issue with point 1, I am seeing over 15 minute delays on consistency of a low level API datastore put on a single entity.

i.e. I update an entity and fetch in 15 minutes later and it will show updated data most of the time, but every 10 cycles or so it shows old data. This seems consistent with this article: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency that seems to say strong consistency can only be had through ancestor queries, but note the 1 request/sec limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.  They just word it slightly differently:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Right at the beginning there are 5 point form features.  The last two describe your question, except that they refer to "reads" instead of "gets".

This probably adds to your confusion, but when they mean "read" or "get", it really means fetching an entity directly - by key or id.  If you call the python 'get' function with an attribute other than the key or id, it's actually issuing a query, which is eventually consistent (unless it's an ancestor query).