# Not getting Datastore strong consistency reads with getById()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I'm not getting strong consistency on Datastore reads like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282395/google-appengine-datastore-constistency).

Code (with `Objectify`).

```
a = getById() // ofy().load().type(this.clazz).id(id).now()

Begin transaction

   ...
   a.count++;
   putSync(a) // ofy().save().entity(entity).now();
   ... 

End transaction
```

Notice that I'm getting the counter with 2817 at 03:01:07, even after updates to 2818 at 03:00:27 and to 2819 at 03:00:47.

```
2015-04-06 03:01:07.582 /rest/x 200 127ms 3kb Java/1.7.0_75 module=x version=v3
2015-04-06 03:01:07.496 [s~primebus01/transmissoes:v3.383369173292091449].<stdout>: After getById() ... 2817
2015-04-06 03:01:07.547 [s~primebus01/transmissoes:v3.383369173292091449].<stdout>: Before putSync() ... 2818

2015-04-06 03:00:47.449 /rest/x 200 216ms 3kb Java/1.7.0_75 module=x version=v3
2015-04-06 03:00:47.339 [s~primebus01/transmissoes:v3.383369173292091449].<stdout>: After getById() ... 2818
2015-04-06 03:00:47.395 [s~primebus01/transmissoes:v3.383369173292091449].<stdout>: Before putSync() ... 2819

2015-04-06 03:00:27.227 /rest/x 200 189ms 3kb Java/1.7.0_75 module=x version=v3
2015-04-06 03:00:27.122 [s~primebus01/transmissoes:v3.383369173292091449].<stdout>: After getById() ... 2817
2015-04-06 03:00:27.174 [S~Primebus01/Transmissoes:v3.383369173292091449].<Stdout>: Before PutSync() ... 2818
```

This behavior occurs only at very specific times during a day.

Wasn't supposed reads (by id) return strong consistency results?

What is wrong? Or is it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity is being overwritten. Log publish time could be different from object update time.

You need to call `getById()` from inside the transaction. As explained here (from Objectify's wiki):

```
Thing th = ofy().transact(new Work<Thing>() {
    public Thing run() {
        Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
        thing.modify();
        ofy().save().entity(thing);
        return thing;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi tj, you've missed wiki link. Could you explain how it "is being overwritten"? I think this is not possible because I'm using a putSync(), that is, it just returns when my entity get updated on two datacenters (high replication).

Comment: Your transaction has no practical effect because you aren't loading the entity inside the transaction. You could be seeing the result of collisions.

Comment: Objectify's user guide starts here: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts  You would be well served to read it through, especially the part on transactions.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I've been following Objectify since 3.1. Good work. I've made a mistake, I was reading entity inside a transaction. Actually, the issue was with a paralel process that was updating the same entity without a transaction. I think that should also have been done inside a transaction. Right? Sugestion: you could improve guide with an example explaining what happens with Objectify/Datastore when paralel process updates same entity raising ConcurrentModificationException.